# How do I prevent a table from extending past its containers height

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a table and whenever there are too many rows it goes off the bottom of the page and exceeds its containers height.
[image]

```
<body>
  <div class="myContainer">
    <table class="scrolldown">

      <!-- Table head content -->
      <thead class="test1">
        <tr>
          <th>Heading 1</th>
          <th>Heading 2</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>

      <!-- Table body content -->
      <tbody class="test2">
        <tr>
          <td>Content</td>
          <td>Content</td>
        </tr>...
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
<body>
```

CSS

```
.myContainer {
  outline-style: solid;
  outline-color: #c7d2fe;
  height: 100px
}
tbody td,
thead th {
  width: 200px;
  border-right: 2px solid black;
}
td {
  text-align: center;
}
```

How can I make it so that the table becomes scrollable once it would extend past its containers height?

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9j2epto7/47/)

Comment: Watch out! You're missing some semi-colons in your question and fiddle. This can cause CSS after the missing semi-colon to not work.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by adding `overflow: auto;` to the wrapper div `.myContainer`.

This will add a scrollbar to the container when the table is taller.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/df8rvbu3/)